# Clarification of Haskell mutual recursion

Tags: haskell, types, mutual-recursion

I've come across these discussions of *mutual recursion*, initially in the context of the `let` expression, i.e., a `let` allows for bindings to refer to one another with no mind for order. (See [here](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html).) I then saw [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion) discussion in Wikipedia. This gives an example in the form of a data type in SML

```
datatype 'a tree = Empty | Node of 'a * 'a forest
and      'a forest = Nil | Cons of 'a tree * 'a forest
```

As I recall, the `and` is necessary for a mutual recursive relationship. It led to this version in Haskell

```
data Tree a = Empty
            | Node (a, Forest a)
data Forest a = Nil
              | Cons (Tree a) (Forest a)
```

I have an intuitive grasp of this, but the syntax is confusion, e.g., the SML `tree` has

```
... Node of 'a * 'a forest
```

This is a tuple, correct? And yes, I think I'm seeing a tuple in the Haskell translation

```
... Node (a, Forest a)
```

Intuitively, this is the same as a branch capability where a tree Node may have a whole `Forest` of (one or many) sub-trees, correct? But then the Haskell `Forest` data type basically conses a new `Tree` element to the head of a `Forest` (of `Tree` elements) list, and yet the SML version seems to use a `*`

```
... Cons of 'a tree * 'a forest
```

which means create a tuple? In general, the confusing `Tree` definition, i.e., a `Tree` can have a `Forest` underneath it. Then there is this definition of a tree

```
data Tree = Leaf | Node Int Tree Tree
```

where the issue of sub-trees is limited to two sub-trees. Is using `Forest` the only way to allow one-or-many sub-nodes? Intuitively, trees don't have forests under them, rather, they are members of a forest. One question would be, Can there be a direct use of regular list consing?

```
data Forest a = Nil | ForestCons (Tree a) [(Tree a)] deriving (Show)
```

Comment: The tuple is redundant; `data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Forest a)` is fine.

Comment: In the SML syntax `Node of 'a * 'a Tree` is not a tuple despite looking like one.

Comment: As far as a direct use of regular lists, I think what you're looking for is `type Forest a = [Tree a]`.  You can then combine the types and write `data Tree a = Empty | Node a [Tree a]`

Comment: You may find the `GADTSyntax` language option helpful; instead of this shorthand syntax for ADTs, it lets you write a `data` definition as a list of the type signatures of the constructors that you would see if you asked e.g. `:type Node` in GHCi. In this case, I’d write `data Tree a where { Empty :: Tree a; Node :: a -> Forest a -> Tree a; }` and `data Forest a where { Nil :: Forest a; Cons :: Tree a -> Forest a -> Forest a; }` or the uncurried forms `Node :: (a, Forest a) -> Tree a` & `Cons :: (Tree a, Forest a) -> Forest a` if you include the (unnecessary) tuples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Node (a, Forest a)`, despite being perfectly legal Haskell, is unidiomatic. The conventional form of the definition would be

```
data Tree' a = Empty'
             | Node' a (Forest a)
```

This contains the same information as your `Tree`, but instead of packing the fields of the `Node` constructor in a tuple it just gives them both as fields. The difference is that, when actually dealing with values of the type, you'd write `Node' h t` instead of `Node' (h,t)`.

Likewise, your `Forest` is equivalent to the not recommended form

```
data Forest' a = Nil'
               | Cons' (Tree a, Forest a)
```

Comment: What would be an idiomatic form for `Forest` if not the given one?

Comment: `newtype Forest = Forest { treesList :: [Tree] }`. But your form with `Cons (Tree a) (Forest a)` is also idiomatic, just making things unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Indeed, even a simple `type` alias, rather than a `newtype`, [would be idiomatic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Graph.html#t:Forest).